# How to turn off ChromeVariations on Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android

To turn off [ChromeVariations](https://superuser.com/questions/541466/what-is-the-variations-section-in-the-output-of-aboutversion-or-chrome-v) on Linux, one simply needs to create an /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/*.json file containing `{"ChromeVariations": 1}`. But what about on Android? See [Extend (a way to turn off) ChromeVariations to Android](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1209551).

One needs to be root on Linux to install Chrome, so editing /etc is no problem.
But on Android, one does not need to be root to install Chrome, so one does not wish to, yes, become a *Super User* and "root" one's phone (voiding warranty) to test if putting the same file in /etc on Android will work.

(Why would anybody want to turn off ChromeVariations? Well, just like when we disable Chrome Extensions to make sure it is not one of them causing a bug, we sometime wish to do the same with ChromeVariations. That way we can be sure, why Bill, with the same Chrome version, doesn't get the same results as Mary.)